# Cordova app on iPhone X adds black bar on top of app

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, phonegap

I recently updated my Cordova app to fit the the new iPhone X screen layout. To archive that, I

1. Added "viewport-fit=cover" to the meta-tag
2. Switched to a storyboard splash screen

As you can see in the attached picture it works fine except for the black bar on the top of the app.

Is there a way to remove the black bar?

[Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kF5yM.png)